# Error occurs while gettting video feed from IP Camera (OpenCV python 3.3)

Tags: python, opencv, decoding, ip-camera

I am trying get video from IP Camera (rtsp protocol) but sometimes these errors come.

[h264 @ 0x509b300] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 16 28
[h264 @ 0x509b300] error while decoding MB 16 28, bytestream 3648

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

please help